is there evidence for geographical determinism? does geography explain differences in human populations around the world?
are there specific reasons why some cultures have built larger empires throughout history and is it motivated by their geographic conditions (poor soil conditions, less arability, poor agricultural output etc.). Also, is level of innovation and inventiveness determined by geography?

That's an awful broad question, isn't it?  And sounds almost like something that would be homework?

On the history stack we would call this a Guns, Germs and Steel question.

New here, thanks for the contribution though.
